# yii update 2 field dropdownlist onchange

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using Yii 1 with AJAX request to update Dropdown list from another dropdown list, my steps are:

1. Click on Freight Forwarder (Customer)
2. Display all operation with status =6 of selected customer
3. The result will be displayed on operation_id dropdown list.

All that is Ok and working.

but now I need to add another step which is

1. Update also Due date according to selected customer.

and Customer table there is terms field which has some numbers, so I need to add current date to that the result from that field.

for example if Customer A his due date is after 20 days, Customer B his due date is after 20 days and so on.

So I can get that one but the problem is how can I do that , can I use same action that I am using (actionGetOperation) from that controller or different actions

.

```
/** this is an action **/   public function actionGetOperation() {
    $data = Operation::model()->findAll('freight_forwarder_id=:freight_forwarder and status=6 and deleted !=1  and company_id  = :company ', 
            array(
                ':freight_forwarder' => (int) $_POST['Invoice'] ['freight_forwarder_id'] ,
                ':company'=> Yii::app()->user->company , 
            ));
    $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'operation_no');
    foreach ($data as $value => $operation_no) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($operation_no), true);
    }
}
```

and this is the action

```
  <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="form-group <?php echo $model->hasErrors('freight_forwarder_id') ? "has-error" : "" ?> ">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'freight_forwarder_id', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label')); ?>

            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <?php
                $options = array(
                    'id' => 'freight_forwarder_id',
                    'class' => 'form-control input-sm',
                    'empty' => '',
                    'ajax' => array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'url' => CController::createUrl('Invoice/GetOperation'),
                         'update' => '#' . CHtml::activeId($model, 'operation_id'),Invoice_operation_id
                        //'update' => '#Invoice_operation_id ,#Invoice_due_date',
                    )
                );

                echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'freight_forwarder_id', CHtml::listData(Freight_forwarder::model()->allFreight_forwarder($contact_category=='customer'? 1 : 2), 'id', 'name'), $options);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div> 


        <div class="form-group <?php echo $model->hasErrors('operation_id') ? "has-error" : "" ?> "  >
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'operation_id', array('class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'operation_id', array(), array('class' => 'form-control input-sm')); ?> </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group <?php echo $model->hasErrors('due_date') ? "has-error" : "" ?> ">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'due_date', array('class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <?php
                $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array('name' => CHtml::activeName($model, 'due_date'), 'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
                    'options' => array('firstDay' => 6, 'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',),
                    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'form-control input-sm'),
                ));
                ?> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: its hard to understand what problem you have and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you Muhamad for your reply, but what I need is when I select a customer from dropdown list it should change 2 field (operation_id & due_date) according to that customer